# Objective c - Draw image with rounded corners in drawRect

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, rounded-corners, drawrect

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `UIImage` as property.
I want to draw the image in drawRect, and to be efficient because this is a table view cell.

I know how to draw the image as it is:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect 
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;

    [self.image drawInRect:rect];
}
```

But how can I draw the image with rounded corners, and stay efficient?

BTW I don't want to use `UIImageView` and then set the layer corner radius because it seams to  hurt performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a clipping path:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
CGContextAddPath(ctx, clippath);
CGContextClip(ctx);
[self.image drawInRect:rect];
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: You can also set the `cornerRadius` property of the underlying core animation layer, but clipping in the `drawRect:` method is more efficient.

Comment: First: What have you tried? Take a look at `CGContextDrawPath` and `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` and come back if you need more help.